# I made the ERD of Database but I think it needs some Normalizing

Tags: database, erd

[image: ERD of restaurant]

I had Database course this term in college and now I have a project of making a Database of a Restaurant.

I made the ERD of Database but I think it has some problem and needs some Normalizing. 
I need some help to check the ERD and find the mistake of it.

Comment: Why do you think it has a problem?

Comment: We normalize logical relations, not conceptual entity-relationship diagrams. Add attributes to your ERD, then translate it into a set of relations, then look at the dependencies among the components. ER models generally produce 3NF or higher relations.